# Simple Oracle Procedure Failing

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a very simple test proc:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TestSproc
    (userName in VARCHAR2, p_Test OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)IS 
BEGIN
    OPEN p_Test FOR
    SELECT * FROM Test_Table 
    WHERE name = userName ;

END TestSproc;
```

When I run the proc (ctrl f10) in sqldeveloper on the proc page I get the result I would expect. But when I try to call the proc with the below query I get the error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - begin  DB.TestSproc('Phil'); end;
>   Error report - ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TestSproc'
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

```
begin 
    DB.TestSproc('Phil');
end;
```

Can anyone please point me in the correct direction.

EDIT

In SQL Server I would simply do:

```
USE DB;  
GO  
EXEC dbo.TestSproc@Name= 'Phil';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Oracle 12c with a 12c client:

```
create or replace procedure testsproc
    ( username in varchar2 )
as
    resultset sys_refcursor;
begin
    open resultset for
        select * from test_table 
        where  name = username;

    dbms_sql.return_result(resultset);
end testsproc;
```

Then call it with

```
exec testsproc('Phil')
```

or

```
call testsproc('Phil');
```

or

```
begin
    testsproc('Phil');
end;
```

depending on what you are calling it from.

[Further reading](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the output *somewhere*, so - declare an appropriate variable:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number, p_emps out sys_refcursor) is
  2  begin
  3    open p_emps for
  4      select deptno, empno, ename
  5      from emp
  6      where deptno = par_deptno;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> var l_out refcursor
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    p_test(10, :l_out);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> print :l_out;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME
---------- ---------- ----------
        10       7839 KING
        10       7782 CLARK
        10       7934 MILLER

SQL>
```

Comment: This is SQLPlus session, with 4 separate parts: CREATE PROCEDURE is one "script", variable declaration another, an anonymous PL/SQL block that runs the procedure is the third, and *print* is fourth. So, what do you call "one script"?

Comment: Sorry I must not be fully understanding. When I call the begin block it doesn't know what p_test is. I want to call the proc from a query that is on a different page/file. For example in SQL server I would have sproc saved and then I would create a new query to call it e.g. to test

Comment: @Phil3992 When you say `I would create a new query to call`..Does this mean you call it via a select statement.

Comment: @XING no. I would execute from a blank query page.E.g like so:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure

This is what I want to do in oracle. But it seems waymore convoluted on this DBMS. How I wish the project I was on just used  SQL server

Comment: P_TEST is a stored procedure, which means it resides in the database and is owned by user that created it. You can call it from anywhere, as long as you have access to it (i.e. from an SQLPlus session, SQL Developer, TOAD, Apex, Forms, ...). So, nothing stops you from calling it from a "blank query page" (whatever it is).

Comment: @Phil3992 You can read my answer below. As far i could understand you needed the way is showed below.