# PL/SQL SELECT Statement Containing only Variables Results in PLS-00428

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL batch that performs an `UPDATE` followed by an `INSERT`. From this batch, I would like to return the number of rows updated and the number of rows inserted.

I can retrieve these numbers by storing `sql%rowcount` in ROWS_UPDATED and ROWS_INSERTED variables after each respective SQL statement. The problem occurs when I attempt to return the counts from the batch using a `SELECT` statement.

Here is a minimal sample that reproduces the error I am encountering:

```
DECLARE 
    ROWS_UPDATED NUMBER := 0;
    ROWS_INSERTED NUMBER := 0;
    ROWS_DELETED NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

    SELECT ROWS_INSERTED, ROWS_UPDATED, ROWS_DELETED FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Oracle reports the following error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What is the correct way, if any, to achieve my goal? I've searched the Internet like crazy and can't seem to find a way to do this. I need to return these values from the batch so that an ETL package can consume the values for reporting purposes.

**Important:** I need this to work in a batch. I cannot create a function or a subprogram on the target database. For that reason, I do not believe using the `return` keyword is an option.

**Not a Duplicate**: The suggested duplicate article concerns using `SELECT INTO` and using `dbms_output` to return the value. I need to return the results of the `SELECT` directly for immediate consumption by an SSIS ETL package. The return value of the batch must be a multi-column result set. It is possible that the error I am encountering indicates that I am using the wrong technique to achieve my goal; I can accept that. I need to know how to return a `SELECT` containing only variable values from a batch.

Comment: How will SSIS call this? You could open a ref cursor to return the results; or if this is really a procedure call via an out parameter (though in that case you coudl have two scalar our parms instead, for the two counts); or from 12c you can open a cursor and use `dbms_sql.return_results`. Depends how it'll be consumed, and which version of Oracle you're using.

Comment: If it's about [implicit resultsets](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1) then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204560/simple-oracle-procedure-failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `INTO` to make a select query within a PLSQL block.

```
SQL> begin
  2      select 1 from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /
    select 1 from dual;
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement


SQL> declare
  2      vVar number;
  3  begin
  4      select 1 into vVar from dual;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If you need to print the result of a query, a way could be DBMS_OUTPUT:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2      vVar number;
  3  begin
  4      select 1 into vVar from dual;
  5      --
  6      dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || vVar);
  7  end;
  8  /
Result: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Regarding `SELECT...FROM DUAL`: I was under the impression (from the documentation) that you could only select a single value. Is that not correct?

Comment: Also, `dbms_output` will not work in this scenario, since the return value from the batch *must* be a multi-column result set.

Comment: You can use `DUAL` to select a single row, with as many columns as you need (`select 1, 2, 3 from dual` gives a row with three columns). About the script, a script does not return anything. If you need to get some output from a script, a way could be writing to a file with `DBMS_OUTPUT` and the `SPOOL` command

Comment: So then, the short and skinny of it is that I would have to create a file containing the results, and then parse the file. Ugh. Not pretty. But if that's how it is, that's how it is. Thank you for your response. It's appreciated.

Comment: I agree, that's not a great way, but I don't think there's a better way to get something out from a script. Let's see if someone has a better idea...

Comment: @MikeHofer The concept of spooling to a file is from [SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SQL-Plus-quick-start.html) (the command-line tool). Is that what you are using in your batch? From your question it didn't seem like it.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson No, I'm using an Execute Sql task in an ETL package. It essentially opens a connection to Oracle, and executes the SQL batch directly. SQL*Plus is not involved.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSIS but looks like it has a facility to capture a result set, in which case it may handle Oracle implicit result sets (new feature in Oracle 12c) - see my comment on your question.